# Using mingw/msys just for its posix tools: mount point question

Tags: windows, cygwin, posix, mingw, msys

I write cross-platform software, so I like my Windows environment to be Un*x-like (I'm an old Unix/IRIX/Linux geek).  I just care about shells and tools, not so much about compilers or the build environment (I have a real industrial-strength build system that doesn't depend on mingw or cygwin).  I just want a shell window on my Windows box that works like a POSIX system.

I'd like to move away from cygwin and its CRLF weirdness and dll-dependencies and update troubles, and maybe replace it with mingw/msys.  I've started to do this, but am stumped on one thing.  I really really need mingw paths to map to the same Windows paths.  So / must be c:/ and /windows -> c:/windows and so on.  Mingw's default mount setup ends up like a chroot, with mingw "/" mapping to c:/mingw or something like that.  You have to use drive prefixes like /c/windows to get to /Windows.  I'm happy to tweak my $PATH and whatever else I need to do to make this work.  Does anyone have any hints?

Comment: Also, if you don't want the MinGW compilers and build tools, I'd have thought that cygwin might be the better bet, and I'm very far from being a cygwin fan.

Comment: Neil, maybe you're right and I should just stick with cygwin then, esp. if it has the same mount and EOL issues of cygwin.  I was hoping to get something lighter weight.

I don't care at all about mingw really.  I just want a posixy shell and tools that let me navigate my windows box like a linux box.  I just want bash, ls, find, cat, patch, and all those things to "just work."   I don't want to be in a chroot jail just to have a posixy environment; I want "/" to be the root of my system drive.  From what you say, seems like msys isn't ready to be the main command-line toolset for a Win box.

Comment: @ganyo Well, it is my main command-line tool (the thought of using cmd or similar makes me shudder) but I don't have your problems with the mount points - they seem quite sensible to me. And I'm a heavy user of MinGW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install Cygwin into C:/, in which case / does become C:/. Dunno whether that can be done with MSYS.

Btw, MSYS is a fork of Cygwin 1.3.3 from 9 years ago, which hasn't seen an awful lot of development compared to Cygwin proper. It has the same approach to line ending issues, allowing both binmode and textmode mounts.